# How do I view both the prediction and the image on the same page in Flask?

Tags: image, flask, view, predict

I have run a model that predicts whether an image is a lake or an ocean.  I have been able to serve this model successfully on my local host where I upload an image and it predicts the class (ocean or lake) as well as the probability/confidence.  I can return that result or I can return the image, but for some reason I cannot return both the image and the prediction result.

I have searched stackoverflow and github and tried many different things per the comment code.  I can display an image from the web, but I can't display the image that was uploaded.  I have read and leveraged code from Github but that only returns the image without the prediction results

```
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
import os
from werkzeug import secure_filename

from flask import send_from_directory

UPLOAD_FOLDER = ''
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['jpg'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']

        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            image = open_image(filename)
            image_url = url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename)
            #print(learn.predict(image))
            ok = learn.predict(image)
            first = round(ok[2].data.tolist()[0], 4)*100
            second = round(ok[2].data.tolist()[1], 4)*100
            if first > second:
                okp = first
            else:
                okp = second
            #return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename)) I can get this to work
            #return '''url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename)'''
            #return '''<img src = "{{image}}"/>'''
            #return '''<h1>The prediction is: {}</h1><h1>With a confidence of: {}%'''.format(ok[0], okp)
            return '''<h1>The prediction is: {}</h1><h1>With a confidence of: {}%</h1>
            <img src= "{{image_url}}" height = "85" width="200"/>'''.format(ok[0], okp)
            #return '''<img src = "{{send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)}}"/>'''



    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload a jpg of an Ocean or a Lake</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=False)
```

This is what I get:

The prediction is: oceans
With a confidence of: 94.66%
Then the icon of a pic when a pic is not there

[image: Return Result]

I would like to show the image that was uploaded along with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the `image_url` value in your `<img href="...">` attribute:

```
return '''<h1>The prediction is: {}</h1><h1>With a confidence of: {}%</h1>
<img src="{}" height = "85" width="200"/>'''.format(ok[0], okp, image_url)
```

You can't use `{{image_url}}` syntax, that'd require that you used the Jinja2 template feature of Flask.

`image_url` is the string that you generated for the `uploaded_file()` view, so the browser knows where to load the image from to fill the `<img />` tag in the HTML page.

Comment: Thanks!!  That worked, so much appreciated.  Thanks also for the explanation that makes this more clear.